# Need sample code to load extension on Chrome browser after launching it through selenium

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, capybara, chromium

I am trying to launch Chrome browser using Selenium with extension added to it. But i am getting below error.

Error - Could not load extension from ''. Manifest file is missing or unreadable.

**My Code:**

```
when "CHROME"
chrome_extensions = []
begin
  File.open('/Users/chinmayajb/Downloads/MPM_testing/packages/extension_1_2_4.crx', "rb") do |file|
    chrome_extensions << Base64.encode64(file.read.chomp)
    puts 'Encoded....'
  end
rescue Exception => e
  raise "ERROR: Couldn't File.read or Base64.encode64 a Chrome extension: #{e.message}"
end
caps_opts = {'chrome.switches' => chrome_extensions}
  chrome_switches = %w[--enable-logging --v=1 --disable-popup-blocking --disable-extensions-file-access-check --always-authorize-plugins --disable-improved-download-protection --allow-file-access --load-extension='caps_opts']

  Capybara.register_driver :selenium_chrome do |app|
    # Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome, :desired_capabilities => capabilities)
    Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome, :switches => chrome_switches)
    # Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome, :switches => ["--allow-legacy-extension-manifests--load-extension=/Users/chinmayajb/Downloads/MPM_testing/packages/extension_1_2_4.crx"])
  end
  Capybara.default_driver = :selenium_chrome
```

end

Comment: --load-extensions loads an unpacked extension, not a crx file